# in Java SWT how to draw an animated dash lines on a cell

Tags: java, graphics, swt, rcp

in Java SWT how to draw an animated dash lines on a caption (like in XL when you type control-C)

[image: Animated box]

```
dashOffset 
gc.getLineAttributes and gc.setLineAttributes
gc.setLineDash(new int[] {10,10});
```

I expect the same as on excel when you type ctrl-X : a frame with animated dashes

Comment: SWT doesn't do animation. You might be able to do something with `Display.timerExec` to redraw different lines.